# OCaml Error: Required module `Core__Core_sys' is unavailable

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I'm having trouble linking a very simple OCaml program:

```
open Core

Format.printf "hello world %s\n"  "foobar";;
Format.printf "argv= %s\n" (Sys.get_argv()).(0) ;;
```

which I compile with

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -thread -package core visitor.ml
```

The compile step always generates the error:

```
Error: Required module `Core__Core_sys' is unavailable
```

I've pinned version 4.0.9, and I can see the file:

```
$ ocamlfind query core
/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.09.0/lib/core
```

and `$ ls -la /home/ubuntu/.opam/4.09.0/lib/core`  shows

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu    17891 Dec  3 20:14 core__Core_sys.cmi
-rw-r--r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu    93777 Dec  3 20:14 core__Core_sys.cmt
-rw-r--r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu    75659 Dec  3 20:14 core__Core_sys.cmti
-rw-r--r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu    16958 Dec  3 20:14 core__Core_sys.cmx
```

I've tried everything I can think of, with no luck.  BTW, I notice that the documentation https://ocaml.org/api/Sys.html makes no mention at all of `get_argv` but if I try just plain `Sys.argv` I get a warning:

```
# Sys.argv ;;
Alert deprecated: Core.Sys.argv
[since 2019-08] Use [Sys.get_argv] instead, which has the correct behavior when [caml_sys_modify_argv] is called.
```

So I conclude that the core OCaml documentation published at ocaml.org is more than two years out of date!  How can one obtain up-to-date documentation, ideally documentation that describes these kinds of newbie errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link the package by adding the `-linkpkg` flag:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -thread -package core -linkpkg visitor.ml
```

Comment: Thank you! Next, during runtime, I got `Failed to load plugin ... no implementation available for ...` which I resolved by adding `-linkall` to the build command.

Comment: Indeed, if you are using plugins that rely on all the library modules to have already been loaded, you need to add `-linkall`.

Answer (score 4):

A few points. First, it looks like you are on a fairly old version of OCaml. Unless you need to stay on 4.09 for some reason, I highly recommend upgrading to the latest version, 4.13.1. Instructions for installing are here: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/up_and_running.html

In case you have any trouble with that, try upgrading to the latest version of opam (the OCaml package manager) and doing `opam update` to download the most up-to-date package index.

Second, it looks like you are trying to use Jane Street's [Core](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/index.html) library, which is a third-party package which is intended as a standard library replacement. As such, it has its own version of the OCaml standard library's `Sys` module, i.e. [`Core.Sys`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Core__/Core_sys/index.html). Regarding the alert that you are getting, the `Core.Sys.argv` value is actually deprecated by Jane Street Core: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Core__/Core_sys/index.html#val-argv

> A single result from get_argv (). This value is indefinitely deprecated. It is kept for compatibility...

This leads us to the final issue, when you try to compile it is unable to find the `core` package. There are a couple of choices here. First, one option is that the `core` package and standard library replacement are actually optional; you may not actually need them. If you're an OCaml beginner you could try sticking with the standard library only (so no `open Core`, no trying to compile with the `core` package).

Another option, if you decide to keep using the `core` package, is to the [dune build system](https://dune.build/) instead of `ocamlfind`. Dune is a powerful, modern OCaml build system that handles almost all aspects of package linking during the build, so you don't need to worry about issuing individual compile commands.

Here's what a `dune` file would look like:

```
(executable
  (name visitor)
  (libraries core))
```

And the `visitor.ml` file would be in the same directory:

```
let () =
  Printf.printf "hello world %s\n" "foobar";
  Printf.printf "argv= %s\n" Sys.argv.(0)
```

Then you would run:

```
dune exec ./visitor.exe
```

The `.exe` is a dune convention, executables across operating systems are given this extension.

Finally, in source code you never actually need `;;`. More about that here: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/terminate-a-line-with-or-or-in-or-nothing/8941/21?u=yawaramin

Note on documentation being out of date: it would help if you could point us to where you got the instructions that led you to this point of confusion. There is a lot of effort to clean up install instructions and modernize documentation, but unfortunately there are a lot of outdated getting started guides out there. The 'Up and Running' link I provided at the top of this answer is the best resource.

Comment: Sigh. I'm working on a project that recommends 4.09 and I am in no position to port it to something newer. That project also appears to use Core, or at least Core_kernel, very heavily. And finally, dune is not an option: 1/2 the code is c++, 1/3rd is scheme and 1/6th is python; and I can't port the build system used there to dune, either.

Comment: It also took me a while to realize that the `Base` and `Core` modules were not base core parts of the language, but third party add-ons. This is a very unfortunate  naming decision, but ... so it goes. Oh well.

Comment: @Linas indeed, especially because OCaml has a built-in library called the 'core library': https://ocaml.org/releases/4.13/htmlman/core.html . Jane Street Core naming is super confusing.